# Salvar link de imagem como arquivo no local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localstorage

Como posso salvar um link (*`http://example.com/img.png`*) no formato do arquivo, que neste caso é .png, utilizando JavaScript e salvando no local storage com `$localStorage` do AngularJS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Baixando e salvando uma imagem

A seguinte função faz uma requisição para obter os dados da imagem, converte os dados recebidos para base 64 usando o `FileReader` e então envia o resultado para uma função callback.

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function downloadImage(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        callback.call(callbank, e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Uma nota importante é que se a imagem estiver em outro domínio em relação ao script isso só vai funcionar se os cabeçalhos CORS estiverem ativados na imagem.

Em seguida, o código para salvar a imagem no `LocalStorage` poderia ser assim:

```js
downloadImage('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kienzle.geschaeft/yellow_MarkerA.png', function(base64String) {
  localStorage.setItem('imagem', base64String);
});
```

E o código para carregar a imagem para um elemento `<img>` assim:

```js
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = localStorage.getItem('imagem');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

#### [Exemplo funcional no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/uw13npLm/)

*Nota: não funciona no editor do SO por restrições no local storage.*

*Nota 2: trechos de código baseados [neste excelente artigo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-example-savingimages).*

## Salvando uma imagem existente na página atual

A função abaixo recupera o valor em base 64 de uma imagem na página atual:

```js
function toBase64String(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL;
}
```

O código para salvar a imagem para o `LocalStorage` é:

```js
localStorage.setItem('minha-imagem', toBase64String(document.getElementById('original')));
```

E, finalmente, para restaurar a imagem:

```js
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = localStorage.getItem('minha-imagem');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Este é o mesmo código anterior, com exceção que eu mudei o nome do elemento armazenado no `LocalStorage`.

#### [Exemplo funcional no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/7mbf8nnu/)

*Nota: parte do código foi baseada [nesta questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page).*

Comment: Uma vez, estive estudando compressão de strings para localStorage, mas não cheguei a implementar nada. Provavlemente necessário num caso como este, mas aí não tenho certeza se o `toBase64String` faz alguma compressão. Relacionado: [Storing compressed json data in local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20773945/1287812) e [javascript string compression with localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6865185/1287812)